# Building Jasperreport Textfield message with multiple parameters and types

Tags: jasper-reports

Im trying to create a message in a textfield which uses a localized string in a properties file. The string has 5 parameters, 1 string, 2 numbers and 2 dates.

For some reason i get this message when trying to compile it.

The method msg(String, Object) in the type JREvaluator is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, Integer, Integer, Date, Date)

Here is the textfield

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="5c7c4cab-cbd4-4c0b-8393-c3b5ba3bc856" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="530" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[msg($R{report.title},$P{QUERY_LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME},
$P{QUERY_START_ACCOUNT_NUMBER},
$P{QUERY_END_ACCOUNT_NUMBER},
$P{QUERY_START_DATE},
$P{QUERY_END_DATE}
)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

And here is the properties string

```
report.title=Finanskonti for {0} | Konti: {1, number} - {2,number} | Datoer: {3,date} - {4,date}
```

Got any ideas what im doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working using this code

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement uuid="5c7c4cab-cbd4-4c0b-8393-c3b5ba3bc856" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="530" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[msg($R{report.title}, new Object[]{$P{QUERY_LEGAL_ENTITY_NAME},
$P{QUERY_START_ACCOUNT_NUMBER},
$P{QUERY_END_ACCOUNT_NUMBER},
(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")).format($P{QUERY_START_DATE}),
(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")).format($P{QUERY_END_DATE})}
)]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

hope someone else can use it.